# Angular component testing no provider for service

Tags: angular, angular-test

I have a component, service and mock service. I am writing a simple test for the component but I get an error while testing. I want to use the
MyMockService instead of MyService via useClass.

Angular Version: 11.0.6
Node Version: 14.15.4

component:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    constructor(
      private sharedService: MySharedService,
      private myService: MyService) {}
    ...
}
```

spec.file:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MyService } from '../my.service';
import { MySharedService } from '../my-shared.service';
import { MyMockService } from '../my.service.mock';

import { CountriesComponent } from './countries.component';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let component: MyComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
  let service: MyService;

  beforeEach(async () => {

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [MyComponent],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: MyService, useClass: MyMockService }, // <--
        MySharedService,
      ],
    })
      .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent); // <-- ERROR !!!

    service = TestBed.inject(MyService);

    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

my.service:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService extends MyBaseService {

  baseUrl = '/baseUrl/...';
  constructor(
    protected hc: HttpClient
  ) {
    super(hc);
  }

  get() {
    return this.hc.get<any[]>(`${this.baseUrl}`);
  }

}
```

my.service.mock:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyMockService {

    arr: any[] = [];

    constructor(
    ) { }

    get() {
        return of(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.arr)));
    }
}
```

I get an error when the component is created:

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[MyService -> MyService]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for MyService !
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Could you move the contents of the second `beforeEach` to the first one?

Comment: I tried this. Unfortunately, did not solve.

Comment: can you show the content of the services?

Comment: @Chris  I added the content of the services to the question.

Comment: @kursatsonmez you don't have any error in this code, can you show all imports from spec file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the file path. I had another service with the same name.
I changed the path from

`import { MyService } from '../my.service';`

to

`import { MyService } from '../right path/my.service';`